# Fixing broken html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage Where I want to stop all request and replace my custom html , When I stop using window.stop(); only following html is loaded , I want to replace this with my custom html.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head id="Head1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Test</title>
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../BaseMasterPage/styles/jquery.autocomplete.css">

   </head>
</html>
```

I want to remove everything and show my custom html like below

```
var htmlc ='<html><head><script language="Javascript">function Hi() {alert("Goodbye World");}</script></head><body onload="Hi();">New Content</body></html>';

        document.open();
        document.write(htmlc);
        document.close();
```

But it is not working since original document does not have body or broken , or when I try to add body with below code

```
  var body = document.createElement("body");
    body.innerHTML = "<p>hello world</p>";
    document.firstChild.appendChild(body);
```

I get following error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
```

Note : I am using tampermonkey to modify one website.

Comment: Have you tried setting `document.body = body`?

Comment: try with var body = document.createElement("body");
    body.innerHTML = "<p>hello world</p>";
document.querySelector("html").appendChild(body);

Comment: why is document.write not working after stop(); ?